# ContentDocumentID is not available just after ContentVersion getting inserted But available after soql query

Tags: apex, contentversion, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I am inserting ContentVersion as following:-

```
String yourFiles = 'Lets assume this is your binary string of the files';
ContentVersion conVer = new ContentVersion();
conVer.ContentLocation = 'S'; // S specify this document is in SF, use E for external files
conVer.PathOnClient = 'ionicLogo.png'; // The files name, extension is very important here which will help the file in preview.
conVer.Title = 'Proposal '; // Display name of the files
conVer.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(yourFiles); // converting your binary string to Blog
insert conVer;
```

Then i used system debug to get ContentDocumentId as following:-

```
system.debug( 'id'+conVer.ContentDocumentId);
```

But when i check the debug log i got null value.

After that, I run a soql query on ContentVersion as following:-

```
ContentVersion cv=[select id, ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion where id=:conVer.id];
system.debug('id'+cv.ContentDocumentId);
```

Here I got the ContentDocumentid for the above inserted ContentVersion.

But i know once you insert contentversion through anonymous window in developer console,one contentDocumentlink with linkentityid equals to user id and one contentDocument is also inserted.

```
ContentDocumentLink cdl=[select id from ContentDocumentLink where ContentDocumentId =:cv.ContentDocumentId];
system.debug(cdl);
contentDocument cd=[select id from contentDocument where id=:cv.ContentDocumentId];
system.debug(cd);
```

I am getting the values in debug log for both the debugs.

My question is why i am not able to directly fetch the contentdocumentid just after insertion of contentVersion record but can fetch by doing a soql query on same contentVersion???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only value that gets updated in the Apex instance for any SObject when you insert is the `Id` value. Other fields populated as part of the insert by triggers or other logic have to be re-queried to get the values -  `ContentVersion` is no different.

Quite a lot can go on behind the scenes for `ContentVersion`, including the automatic addition of a `ContentDocumentLink` to the `User` who inserted the version.

I've found `ContentNote`/`ContentDocument`/`ContentVersion`/`ContentDocumentLink` quite awkward to work with compared to e.g. just a `Note`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As you said, I have tried debugging other fields too just after insertion, i can able to fetch those value in debug logs. Only exception is ContentDocumentID.

Comment: Fabulous answer. was struggling with this for quite some time.